# What is voltbase and timebase?

Tags: oscilloscope

I worked with a digital oscilloscope which could automatically save data on a pendrive, but when I checked the data, I found it in different form. In excel sheet are given two things named "timebase" and "voltbase". I think I need to use these two things to convert data to correct form. Can anyone help me how should I use these two things?

[image]

I used following oscilloscope:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete row 3.
2. Left click on cell A1 and hold.
3. Drag through B:xxx where XXX is the end row of the data.
4. Click the CHART button.

The X dimension (time) is 2,000,000,000ps each, or 2ms.
The Y dimension (voltage) is 10,000,000µV or 10v.

Change the labels of the chart to reflect this, or do some math on these values and create another chart.

Comment: I understand the steps, thanks. I think it is 1V in place of 10V?

Comment: Yes it is 1V (one million µV). Weird style to display time in ps and voltage in µV for the given values.

Comment: Thanks, I have one more doubt. The voltage values coming out of such calculation are very large, beyond 1000V as well. The image of oscilloscope shows Pk-Pk values of around 7.75V in the oscilloscope image, I don't see good agreement between these two values!

Comment: The "voltbase" is probably using the wrong unit and you should divide all your results by 1000.